# Call a procedure with a schema that has a Backslash in it

Tags: sql-server, backslash

I tried the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask but it did not work, so I am asking a new question:

I know this is not a reproducible example.

```
EXEC
mhg\EDW_TM_DSA_CR_Nonemployee.O_E  @data     =   "[Reporting].[mhg\EDW_TM_DSA_CR_Nonemployee].emergencyDx_O_E_data",
   @subject   =   "PersonID",
   @feature   =   "NomenclatureID",
   @target    =   "cohort"
GO
```

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parse error at line: 2, column: 4: Incorrect syntax near '\'.

I think the backslash in my schema name is causing an error.

```
CREATE PROC [mhg\EDW_TM_DSA_CR_Nonemployee].O_E 
-- Identify the relationship between two class variables where
-- It is desired to know what levels of feature predicts target
-- in the data set data with subeject subject subject.
-- Currently the Observed over Expected is calculated from the data
-- Using assumming a gamma distribution with prior of alpha = 10 and beta = 10.

   @data    nvarchar(128),
   @subject   nvarchar(128),
   @feature  nvarchar(128),
   @target nvarchar(128)
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(max)

set @cmd = '
with person
as
(
   select count(distinct [' + @subject + '] ) as count_person, [' + @feature + '] , [' + @target + '] 
   from ' +  @data +
   ' group by [' + @feature + '] , [' + @target + ']
   )
,
target  
as
(
   select count(distinct [' + @subject + '] ) as count_target, [' + @target + '] 
   from ' +  @data +
   ' group by [' + @target + '] 
)
,
feature 
as
(
 select count(distinct [' + @subject + '] ) as count_feature, [' + @feature + '] 
   from ' +  @data +
   ' group by [' + @feature + '] 
)
,
totn
as 
(
   select count(distinct [' + @subject + '] ) as count_tot 
   from ' +  @data +
   ' )



SELECT  a.[' + @feature + '] , a.[' + @target + '] , 
        a.count_person, c.count_feature,
       b.count_target, d.count_tot,
       a.count_person  as observed,
       (1.0 *c.count_feature * b.count_target )/(1.0 * d.count_tot) as expected,
       (a.count_person/(c.count_feature + .001))/((b.count_target + .001)/d.count_tot) as RR,
       (a.count_person + 10.0) / (1.0 * b.count_target * c.count_feature/d.count_tot + 10.0) as O_E_adj

FROM Person as a
JOIN target  as b
on a.[' + @target + '] = b.[' + @target + ']
JOIN feature  as c
on a.[' + @feature + '] = c.[' + @feature + '] 
CROSS join totn as d
order by O_E_adj desc
'
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
END
GO
```

Comment: 1. Why not use the `[]` notation in your call? It's in your definition. 2. Use `'`, not `"` for string literals

Comment: What is the result when the back slash is removed from the schema name? !!!

Comment: Nice - setting yourself up for sql injection. And you should really think about using names that are useful. [at]data is the name of a table. "Data" is a meaningless word - why not name your variable [at]tablename? And the literal you supplied for that parameter is correctly using the bracket delimiters - so use the same approach referencing the procedure name as already suggested. Alternatively - change your schema name so that it follows the regular identifier rules.

Comment: @donPablo Could not find stored procedure 'Reporting.EDW_TM_DSA_CR_Nonemployee.O_E'

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  When I use both of your suggestions, the call works. Thanks.  It turns out this is a "syntax problem" error, but I didn't see that from the error message.

Comment: @SMor  "data" is a perfect name given this can be run on any data and "data" is one letter shorter than "table", which is also a meaningless word.  Also, it is conceivable that this can be useful in cases where the data is not a table.